# Ng-if else Usage

Tags: html, angular, asp.net-mvc

I am using Angular i am beginner, I want to know If and else usage.. i implemented if but else how should i right??

```
                    <text x="{{ODBData[index].left+10}}" y="{{ODBData[index].top+ODBData[index].textsize*1+7}}"
                          fill="{{(ODBData[index].rangeactive)?ODBData[index].textrangecolor:ODBData[index].textcolor}}"
                          ng-if="ODBData[index].data.CustomObjName ==''"
                          stroke="none">
                        {{ODBData[index].data.ObjName[0].slice(0, -6).trim()}}
                    </text>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: Is it **angularjs** or **angular2+**?

Comment: i don't know exactly.. i am new to anguar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Example of use-case of ngIf and else :

```
                <span *ngIf="value>0; else showNegatif">
                  + {{value}}
                 </span>
                <ng-template #showNegatif>
                  <span > - {{value }} </span>
              </ng-template>
```